# MoveIt create PlanningSceneInterface

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to retrieve a collision object that is present in the moveit planning scene to then attach it to a robot link. To do this, I thought of getting the object by its ID using [the getObjects method of the PlanningSceneInterface class.](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1PlanningSceneInterface.html#a1fa1e9196411ab28920f28b57f9f1add) However, when I try to create an object of the PlanningSceneInterface class I get the following error:

```
error: ‘moveit::planning_interface’ has not been declared
 moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface scene_interface;
```

I am including the class with the following line:

```
#include <moveit/planning_interface/planning_interface.h>
```

I am running ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04, with gcc 7.5.0.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380936/moveit-create-planningsceneinterface/) by [sdbonhof](https://answers.ros.org/users/70429/sdbonhof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-25**:
@sdbonhof: please do not edit titles to add things like `solved` or `answered` to them. Just marking the question as answered by clicking the checkmark is enough. It will clearly show the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The header is actually: `moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h`. It is part of the planning_scene_interface package, which is in the planning_interface folder of moveit_ros. That is probably where the namespace comes from.

See the [header](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/melodic-devel/moveit_ros/planning_interface/planning_scene_interface/include/moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h) at the Github repository.

---

Originally posted by [pvl](https://answers.ros.org/users/74901/pvl/) with karma: 111 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdbonhof](https://answers.ros.org/users/70429/sdbonhof/) on 2021-06-25**:
This worked, thanks!